# Import Data from Oracle using Spark

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, databricks

In Databricks I am using the following code to extract data from Oracle.

```
%scala
val empDF = spark.read 
    .format("jdbc") 
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password//hostname:port/sid") 
    .option("dbtable", "EMP") 
    .option("user", "username") 
    .option("password", "password") 
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") 
    .load()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

`ojdbc6.jar` is attached to the cluster as a library.

I need to connect to Oracle to read the table data. The table also has BLOB data.

Comment: Why do you have `username/password` is the URL? Also, possibly a later issue, `sid` should be the service name, which may be the same of course.

Comment: use jdbc:oracle:@//hostname:port/sid .Also, some hostnames has DNS resolvance issues with Spark workers and the solution is to add them to Spark known hosts or use ip address directly instead of hostname

Comment: I would first do the telnet test with the port on the Oracle database from where ever I'm running the spark application form.  Spark driver program can run on any of the nodes, so its better to do the telnet test from random nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should double check that your Apache Spark™ cluster has network access to your Oracle Database by:

```
%sh
telnet <host> <port>
```

I assume that your Oracle instance is also running in your cloud account. You may need to do VPC peering (if on AWS) to allow for a connection between Databricks' clusters and the database instance in another VPC for private access. If there is no privacy concern, you can open up to the world through the security group settings.

Secondly, your jdbc URL may not be correct. Please review this [sample oracle connection](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/oracle.html), as well as this [jdbc connection guide](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#establish-cloud-connectivity).