# Databricks Reading Only metadata from JDBC Source but not Data

Tags: oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Tried different ways

sql

```
  CREATE TABLE oracle_table
  USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
  OPTIONS (
    dbtable 'persons',
    driver 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    user '<user>',
    password '<pass>',
    url 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@<host>:1521/orcl')
```

above code returned OK

```
select * from oracle_table
```

throwed java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

python

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521/orcl"
properties = {
    "user": "<user>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
}

pushdown_query = "( SELECT * FROM persons ) emp_alias"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=properties)
df.printSchema()
```

returned

```
 |-- PERSON_ID: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- FIRST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LAST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

But for below code

```
df.show()
```

throwed java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

help me!

Comment: Does the `CREATE TABLE` run straight away? It's probably "lazy loading", meaning that it doesn't run until you actually select from it. So most likely the issue is actually in your create table, and your databricks actually can't connect to `<host>:1521`. Are you certain your databricks install has network connectivity to the Oracle server?

Comment: Initally i have faced connectivity error,i have updated the azure inbound and outbound rules ,then it is able to load metadata from table ```DESCRIBE persons``` is also giving all columns and datatypes, if there is connectivity issue is shoudn't load the metadata also right!, thats what confusing me

Comment: @ChandraPrakash You may checkout similar issue discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542816/import-data-from-oracle-using-spark

Comment: The `%sh` telnet trick is pretty handy I'll have to remember that one

Comment: %sh ping <host> is working and also %sh telnet <host> <port> also working problem here is im unable to fetch data, how ever dataframe is loaded with schema,  its really confusing and unable to figureout what is is wrong

Comment: i figured out the issue firewall is enabled for only master node of databricks and workers are in private ip .Thats why im able to get metadata but not data

Comment: @ChandraPrakash, I had posted that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

> I figured out the issue firewall is enabled for only master node of databricks and workers are in private ip. That's why I'm able to get metadata but not data.